# Что со знаками?

Tags: пунктуация

**Начало праздника было запланировано на 3 часа дня, однако, уже с самого утра на обычно безлюдной площадке возле Минск-Арены было более чем оживлённо.**

Нужна ли запятая после слова "более" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не нужна. По Розенталю, "запятая не ставится внутри сочетаний  *(не) больше чем, (не) меньше чем*.. и т. п., если они не содержат сравнения: ...*Это **не более как** клевета*...
Но (при наличии сравнения или сопоставления):... *Сипягин волноваллся гораздо **более, чем его гость*** (Т.)."
В приведённом Вами примере сравнения (сопоставления) нет.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна и после *однако*. *Однако* в данном предложении союз, равный по значению союзу *но.*

Comment: Да, согласен с вами.Сам не исправил опечатку.

Answer (score 0):

"Минск-Арена" в кавычках.